# Make movieclips appear randomly in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Right now I have six mice places in spesific places on the stage. These mice move based on adjustments made on the timeline inside the movieclip itself. What I aim to do is to start these six movieclips randomly based on a timer. This task im currently struggeling with..

Here is my code;

```
var clipArray:Array = new Array();

clipArray[0] = musx0_mc;
clipArray[1] = musx1_mc;
clipArray[2] = musx2_mc;
clipArray[3] = musx3_mc;
clipArray[4] = musx4_mc;
clipArray[5] = musx5_mc;



var i:int = 0;

var musTimer:Timer = new Timer(100);

musTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, playMus);

function playMus(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    for(i=0; i<clipArray.length; i++)
    {
        var randomMus:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);        
        clipArray[randomMus].play();
    }
}

musTimer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to get 0 to 5 random number.

```
//var randomMus:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*100); // returns 0 to 99
var randomMus:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);    // returns 0 to 5
```

Maybe this code works.

```
var clipArray:Array = new Array();
clipArray[0] = musx0_mc;
clipArray[1] = musx1_mc;
clipArray[2] = musx2_mc;
clipArray[3] = musx3_mc;
clipArray[4] = musx4_mc;
clipArray[5] = musx5_mc;

var musTimer:Timer = new Timer(100);
musTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, playMus);

function playMus(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    //for(i=0; i<clipArray.length; i++) // What is this loop??
    //{
        //var randomMus:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
        var randomMus:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
        clipArray[randomMus].play();
    //}
}

musTimer.start();
```

Comment: The mice continues to come out of their holes at the same time, even with your adjustments.

Comment: I think this answer is on the right track, the problem is that it can start the same element again. To avoid this, remove the started `MovieClip` from the array and base the index calculation on that. Also, @JonasDuvsethe every `MovieClip` starts playing automatically. Without a `stop()` on the first frame of the time line, they all start at the same time: immediately. The calls to `.play()` that may or may not happen later do not change anything about this.